# Reference antecedent Java stream step without breaking the stream pipeline?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new to functional programming, and I am trying to get better.

Currently, I am experimenting with some code that takes on the following basic form:

```
private static int myMethod(List<Integer> input){
      Map<Integer,Long> freq = input
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
      
      return (int) freq
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(key-> freq.containsKey(freq.get(key)))
        .count();
    }
```

First a hashmap is used to get the frequency of each number in the list. Next, we sum up the amount of keys which have their values that also exist as keys in the map.

What I don't like is how the two streams need to exist apart from one another, where a HashMap is made from a stream only to be instantly and exclusively consumed by another stream.

Is there a way to combine this into one stream? I was thinking something like this:

```
private static int myMethod(List<Integer> input){
      return (int) input
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(key-> freq.containsKey(freq.get(key)))
        .count();
    }
```

but the problem here is there is no freq map to reference, as it is used as part of the pipeline, so the filter cannot do what it needs to do.

In summary, I don't like that this collects to a hashmap only then to convert back into a keyset. Is there a way to "streamline" (pun intended) this operation to

1. Not be going back and forth from stream and hashmap
2. Reference itself in a way without needing to declare a separate map before the pipeline.

Thank you!

Comment: your suggestion should work. However, I see a problem in your suggestion . where are you getting freq to retrieve the key?

Comment: Freq doesn't exist, which is the problem in code sample 2. I don't know if there is a way to self reference, if not - then freq must be declared separately as in code sample 1.

Comment: You could use `collectingAndThen()` but it won't be much prettier.

Comment: just to make sure that i got you is this .filter(key-> freq.containsKey(freq.get(key))
to check the value to be equal to one of the keys or i miss understand it

Comment: return (int) input
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(key-> input.contains(key))
                .count(); try this

Comment: @vaibhavsahu That's a little inefficient, unless `input` can be changed to `Set`.

Comment: I also do not think our code does the same thing @vaibhavsahu as the freq map keeps track of frequencies of the input whereas input is just raw values.

I suppose I could use the valueSet stream (as opposed to keySet) and check thru input that way, but that is more of a workaround than anything else. I'm trying to learn the general flow of functional programming techniques so a general solution (if one even exists for this dilemma) is what I am trying to work towards.

Comment: @AaronC Could you briefly explain what your code is supposed to do? with an example possibly

Comment: This will never be true: `freq.containsKey(freq.get(key))`. `freq.get(key)` returns a `Long`, and the keys of the map are `Integer`. A `Long` object is never equal to an `Integer` object (a primitive `long` may be equal to a primitive `int`, but that’s a different story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keySet is nothing but effectively a `HashSet` formed of your `input`. So, you should make use of temporary storage such that:

```
Set<Integer> freq = new HashSet<>(input);
```

and further count, filter based on values in a single stream pipeline as

```
return (int) input
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                Collectors.counting()))
        .values() // just using the frequencies evaluated
        .stream()
        .filter(count -> freq.contains(count.intValue()))
        .count();
```

Comment: Expending CPU time and heap memory for creating a redundant `HashSet`, just for the sake of letting two operations appear as a single statement, is a more than questionable trade-off. It has reached the level of bizarre when the result isn’t even a single statement, but two statements, just as before.

Comment: @Holger Could you elaborate, why would the `HashSet` be redundant? Are you trying to imply that the initial `List` could have been used to perform the `contains` check? Or that `containsKey` + `get` was equally performant with cheaper memory consumption?

Comment: Of course, `containsKey` or `get` on a `HashMap` has the same performance as `contains` on a `HashSet` (In fact, in OpenJDK, the `HashSet` is a wrapper around a `HashMap`, so `contains` calls `containsKey` under the hood). You gain a small improvement by streaming over `values()` instead of `keySet()`, as you did in your answer, eliminating the need to call `get` for every key, but that doesn’t require the additional `freq` set. The remaining `contains` call is on par with a `containsKey` call.